# Simple GSM network simulator for testing and modification

Tags: mobile, simulation, simulator, gsm

Can someone provide me one of the simplest and best GSM network simulators, so that i can test it and make some modifications in the base stations(BSC) and BTS...thanks

Comment: Can you make the question clearer? What are you testing? What do you want to simulate? GSM network simulators usually cost about 100 000 euros.

Comment: @SList I wanted to test the working of an SMS module of a GSM network....

Comment: Is the device under test an SMSC then?  Network simulators usually test a defined 3GPP interface.  You have to look for a simulator for the particular 3GPP interface that you want to test.